# How to render ModelForm on a modal

Tags: python, django, django-forms

```
def login_request(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect("main:homepage")

            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid Username or Password!!")

        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid Username or Password!!")

    form = AuthenticationForm
    return render(request, "main/login.html", {"form": form})
```

I want to render 'form' on a modal for user login but as modal don't have their own URL, how can I render it, for above code I've taken 'main/login.html' as the template before using modal

Comment: Do you mean that you want the modal with the login form to be available on each and every page ? And if yes, what is supposed to happen in the case of an error - should the user stay on the same page with the modal opened or should it be redirected to a dedicated login page ? In the first case, you will obviously need some js / ajax stuff.

Comment: @Vinay please do not repost the same question multiple times because it was closed before. Explain exactly what you want to do, edit your question if there are comments. I commented on your previous question and you didn't react. It's not clear what you want, so please try to formulate in more detail what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: in your urls.py you can name it something like this: path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'), and in the part of your HTML where you call the modal make sure that in the form you put something like this:<form action="{% url 'login' object.id %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                        <p>User: "{{ object }}"?</p>
                        <input type="submit" value="Confirm">
                    </form>

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers in case of error there will an error message on modal. Isn't there any other option other than ajax?

Comment: @dirkgroten really sorry, I want a modal that is available on each page in the navbar. whenever the user clicks on login, a modal should pop up with a modelform. But as modals don't have any href link to go, it was impossible to send a modalform to it. Thats what i really want.

I've given the login function in views.py with modelform in it.